# What are the differences between Microsoft Test Manager MTM, Team Foundation Server TFS & Visual Studio Test Professional VSTS?

Tags: test-management, visualstudio, mtm, tfs, mstest

Recently I got Visual studio Enterprises Subscription from my company and I was asked to prepare the system for testing,  With the help of support team somehow I manage to set up the system but during the research, I come across three terms:-

1. Microsoft Test Manager(MTM)
2. Visual Studio Test Professional
3. Team Foundation Server (TFS)

Now I am confused that in these three, Please explain me the difference between these & how can I use it for END to END Test Process for any general project?

Comment: Have you googled what those three products do? What have you found out by yourself so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are a programmer you need Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise which is $5,999/user/first year and includes Team Foundation Server online access & Microsoft Test Manager stand alone app.

Anyone doing just QA and no programming can use Visual Studio Test Professional which will cost your company less $2,169/user/first year and only includes Team Foundation Server online access & Microsoft Test Manager stand alone app.

With Visual Studio Team Services all the functionality of Microsoft Test Manager is built into the cloud and accessible via web-browser so there is no need for the stand-alone windows application. The only additional functionality of the stand-alone windows application is the ability to record video of test case steps. You can add test cases in the web browser under Project > Test > Test Plans.

Here is the Visual Studio Product Pricing Breakdown from Microsoft: 
[image: Visual Studio Product Pricing Breakdown from Microsoft]

Here is an example of Test Manager in TFS: 
[image: example of Test Manager in TFS]

Here is an example of Microsoft Test Manager stand alone windows app with similar functionality: 
[image: Microsoft Test Manager stand alone windows app]

If you have any further questions you can always contact MSDN team at 800-759-5474 M-F 5:30 AM-5:30 PM PST as well for your technical questions or you can chat with a sales technician through their website @ https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/#tab-d83539eb2b4c2400472

Comment: If you are not using the VSTS test manager tools and just need the OS and platform licenses for test environment setup, it looks to me like MSDN Pro subscription is cheaper (currently) - you basically pay ~100 less per year and get Visual Studio instead of the VSTS test tools